# IBM WCM Images are not displaying when you open a page in anonymous page?

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm

When you open the same page in authenticated access All the images are displaying

[image]

URL differences are "/wps/wcm/connect/" gives Error and "/wps/wcm/myconnect/" gives me actual image

Answer (score 0):

I can be solved by "set Access" option as "inheritance" to the User role
[image]